# Reset position of clip to original recording time in Reaper

Tags: reaper

I've been splitting audio items in Reaper 3.75 and nudging them slightly forwards and backwards to improve the timing. However, there is one section that I have made worse, and I'd like to just put it back to where it originally was. I can't use undo because I've done other stuff since. Does Reaper have the ability to un-nudge a split piece of a clip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I've managed to work this one out myself with a bit of experimenting. You right-click the item and select **Item Processing** and then **Move Items to Source Preferred Position**. This puts it back in the right place, but will leave any fade outs or fade ins that were introduced as crossfades by the original moving of the item. It looks like you have to remove them manually. Or if you re-join it to the its original neigbour by using **heal splits in items** then the extended fadeouts will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do a Save As on the project, then do the undo, then Save As again.

You should then have one project before the nudge to copy that section from and one project with the changes you wanted to keep to copy that from.